# Do Go implementations store the length of a map?

Tags: dictionary, go

Does a `map` have its length stored somewhere or is it calculated each time we call `len(my_map)`?

The language spec shows this for maps, which doesn't really help:

> The number of `map` elements is called its length. For a map `m`, it can be discovered using the built-in function `len` and may change during execution. Elements may be added during execution using assignments and retrieved with index expressions; they may be removed with the delete built-in function.

Under the "Length and capacity" section we see this:

> The expression `len(s)` is constant if `s` is a `string` constant. The expressions `len(s)` and `cap(s)` are constants if the type of `s` is an `array` or `pointer` to an `array` and the expression `s` does not contain channel receives or (non-constant) function calls; in this case `s` is not evaluated. Otherwise, invocations of `len` and `cap` are not constant and `s` is evaluated.

So it tells us that `s` isn't constant and is evaluated but it doesn't state if it's looked up as a stored value like they do with the `slice` type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't checked the sources, but I wrote a quick benchmark.

It tests 4 maps, 2 where keys are `int`, 2 where keys are `string`.

```
var m1 = make(map[int]int)    // key is of type int, len(m1) = 10
var m2 = make(map[int]int)    // key is of type int, len(m2) = 1000000
var s1 = make(map[string]int) // key is of type string, len(s1) = 10
var s2 = make(map[string]int) // key is of type string, len(s2) = 1000000
```

"Small" maps have 10 elements, "large" maps have a million elements. Maps are populated like this:

```
func init() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        m1[i] = i
        s1[strconv.Itoa(i)] = i
    }
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        m2[i] = i
        s2[strconv.Itoa(i)] = i
    }
}
```

A benchmark function looks like this:

```
func BenchmarkSmallIntMap(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
            _ = len(m1) + len(m1) + len(m1) + len(m1) + len(m1) + len(m1)
        }
    }
}
```

All the others are similar, but using `m2`, `s1` and `s2` obviously. Here are the results:

```
BenchmarkSmallIntMap     1000000              2085 ns/op
BenchmarkLargeIntMap     1000000              2087 ns/op
BenchmarkSmallStringMap  1000000              2087 ns/op
BenchmarkLargeStringMap  1000000              2086 ns/op
```

All are the same which pretty much tells that execution time of `len(m)` does not depend on the map size (number of key-value pairs), which suggests that **map length is stored** and not "counted" when called.

If interested, here is the complete test source: [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SBvcDeACxJ).

And twotwotwo checked the [sources](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c5dff7282e27c640c192edb34b92c5c6459aa804/src/runtime/hashmap.go#L102), **the length is stored**.

Comment: I think this is the struct def. with count in tip: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c5dff7282e27c640c192edb34b92c5c6459aa804/src/runtime/hashmap.go#L102

Comment: Thanks. I was a little suspicious that with the fixed numbers, a manual count may be optimized away (possible if not likely) but @twotwotwo's link helps confirm your result. Much appreciated.